# Tikhonov regularization in the non-negative least square

Tags: python, scipy

I am working on a project that I need to add a regularization into the NNLS algorithm.
Is there a way to add the Tikhonov regularization into the NNLS implementation of scipy [1]?

[2] talks about it, but does not show any implementation. Sklearn has an implementation, but it is not applied to nnls.

[1] http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html

[2] http://icses2012.pwr.wroc.pl/article/34.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Still use

`scipy.optimize.nnls(A1, b1)`, where

```
A1 = np.concatenate((A, lambda*np.matlib.identity(n)))
b1 = np.concatenate((b, numpy.zeros(shape=(n,1))))
```

Comment: Thanks lennon310. One more question: how do I define the value of lambda? I am using 1, but I am not sure if it is the best.

Comment: In theory it depends on the condition number of A. The more ill-posedness A is, the larger lambda value should be chosen. If A is well-posed, lambda should be very close to zero. L curve may be helpful in the parameter selection, check this paper for more details: http://www.math.kent.edu/~reichel/publications/tikcrvL.pdf